# How to transform non-normally distributed data with high frequency of extreme values to both sides?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

I have the following issue:

I want to calculate a repeatability coefficient for a behavioral test, of which I have two observations (= the same behavioral test was conducted twice on each individual). 
I have been told to do this with rpt() function of the rptR package in R, which assumes a Gaussian distribution of the data (Poisson or binomial was also possible, but I guess that does not make sense here).

A histogram of my raw data looks like this (x-axis is showing time until a certain behavior is expressed):

[image: Histogram of my raw data]

As one can see, it is quite far from a Gaussian distribution, which is mainly due to the fact that I have a high frequency of individuals that react quite fast to the test and others do not show the behavior at all and are thus assigned the maximum amount of time. That is, the data is censored on the right site.

My question now is: Is there any kind of transformation that is suitable to transform such data into an approximate Gaussian distribution? I've tried log, square-root, and arcsin(sqrt()) transformation so far, but still all of the transformations do not pass a Shapiro-Wilk test (the arcsin(sqrt()) transformation visually coming the closest though).

Comment: You measure time >= 0 ; hence Gaussian doesn't make sense either.  You should look into (generalizations) of exponential distribution which is more apt for waiting times.  Also the histogram indicates this is censored data - where the time is capped at some max.  Can you give more detail on what your experiment is about?

Comment: You shouldn't analyze censored data without accounting for the censoring.

Comment: The experiment examines the immediate behavioral stress response of fish. I.e., fish have been exposed to a standardized stressor and then put into a box that provides shelter but is open to one side ("Open field test"). I recorded the time until the head and the full body of the fish emerged from the box. If no emergence was observed after 30mins, the maximum time of 1800secs was recorded. This test was conducted twice, i.e., I have two observations for each fish and I want to examine whether the behavior measurements are repeatable (thus robust).

Comment: You shouldn't even be *trying* to make this normal. 

Please edit the question itself with the info in your comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the title assumes something that is not correct and doesn't reflect the true goal of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> The repeatability coefficient is a precision measure which represents
>   the value below which the absolute difference between two repeated
>   test results may be expected to lie with a probability of 95%.

If that is what you mean, then, given your data, I think you need to abandon that part of rptR and do something else. You may have to bootstrap or do a permutation test. If rptR is what you want, then the quantity you want to bootstrap is

$$R=V_G/(V_G+V_R)$$
where $V_G$ is group level variance and $V_R$ is residual variance (see [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/vignettes/rptR.html) for more details). Note that rptR relies on a parametric bootstrap, but here you probably need a nonparametric one. However, later in the same document, it notes that:

> Permutation can be used as a robust alternative or addition to LRT. In
>   the simplest case this will work by randomizing the vector of group
>   identities against the response vector followed by refitting the model
>   to the randomized data and storage of the repeatability for each of
>   many replications.

This may work for your case.